# I'm trying to execute automation code for http://site21.way2sms.com, error in 3rd & 4th line from last

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute automation code for http://site21.way2sms.com,

error in 3rd & 4th line from last
//error code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mobile']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx"); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder, 'Type your message ')]")).sendKeys("call me urgently,need to talk");
```

Tried code:-

```
package testpack;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
     {
        // Run Chromedriver.exe to get chrome browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //Launch site
        driver.get("http://site21.way2sms.com/content/index.html");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxx");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginBTN")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Send SMS']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mobile']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder, 'Type your message ')]")).sendKeys("Call me urgently, need to talk");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("Send")).click();
```

Comment: below 2 lines are not running: 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mobile']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder, 'Type your message ')]")).sendKeys("call me urgently,need to talk");

Comment: Would be great if you post the stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: also, get rid of the useless calls to `Thread.sleep()`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code instead

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frame"))); 
driver.findElementByXPath("//input[contains(@id,'mobile')]").sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@*='message'] | //*[@*='Type your message here or use SMS greetings']").sendKeys("test smsm");
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@*='Send'] | //*[@*='return sendMessage();']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code :

```
        driver.switchTo().frame("frame");
        driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@placeholder, 'Type your message ')]")).sendKeys("Call me urgently, need to talk");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("Send")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

your code is fine but you missed to switch to the frame.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/449Hu.png)